# Cast query result to list of anonymous class

Tags: sql, vb.net, list, select, casting

Can anyone give me a method to convert the result of a select query to list of class?
*I want that so I can later use LINK to objects.*

I'm using sql server 2008 and vb.net.
For example, I have a table in DB having two columns:

```
{ProductID, ProductName}
```

I execute a select query `"Select * From Products"` and fill it in a dataset DS.
I want a way so I can convert the result of the above query's result (or any query that returns any set of result) to a list of an existing class in my vb.net project, in my example Product class that has two properties (ProductID and ProductName).
I hope my question is clear enough.

Comment: Have you considered looping through your dataset and putting the results in an ArrayList?

Comment: Yes I thought of it, but actually I don't know if it will be easier then to cast it into a list of my class. Sorry but I'm kind of new to this!

Comment: That's okay. You've got a good question. I always opt for the ArrayList but maybe there is a faster way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the Cast method of IEnumerable:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb341406(v=vs.100).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb341406%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)